# Prop is undefined on Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

HTML passed props to the Vue tag, no value existed. Even if I tried to print out mounted, created, undefined was printed.

Vue is running on the Django Server. So I changed delimiters and printed the apps, but nothing was printed out.

HTML Code

```html
<radio-input :radio-content="personal"></radio-input>
```

Vue Code

```
radioInput = new Vue({
  props: ["radioContent"],
  template:
    '<label>\n' +
    ' <input type="radio" :name="name" :value="value" :v-model="v_model" :required="required">\n' +
    ' <span>${ radioContent }</span>\n' +
    '</label>\n',
  delimiters: ['${', '}'],
  el: 'radio-input',
  data: {
    name: 'A1_P1_S1_B0',
    value: 'personal',
    v_model: 'A1P1S1Q',
    required: true,
  }
});
```

Expected Result is "radioButton + 'personal' text". But "personal" text is not printed

Comment: to display some expression value on tag, should be: `<span>{{ radioContent }}</span>`

Comment: A risk of template tag conflict exists because I am using a "Django" server. That's why I changed delimiters.

Comment: How are you defining `personal`?

Comment: Since you checked in hooks too, we'll need to see how're you passing `personal` from parent to `<radio-input/>` component to help out.

Comment: `personal` variable is not defined in Javascript. HTML codes passed `personal` values to Props.

Comment: [This link](https://codepen.io/ji5485/pen/OJLgLao) is Vue application that embody that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `personal` is not a variable in the parents's data albeit its a static value that is passed to the `<radio-input/>` component.

> To pass static props **`binding colons :someProp`** are not needed. When you use that its basically **`v-bind:someProp`** where the Vue component is going to look for **`someProp`** in its `data` or would try to consider it as a javascript expression like `Number` or `Boolean` or `Array` and not as static text to be passed on.

Change the HTML code for component to:

```
<radio-input radio-content="personal"></radio-input>
```

**--Update based on code snippet & comment--:**
Okay! couple of things here

- **`props`** in Vue are something that is passed on from parent to child (consider it a way of communicating things parent->child which are Vue components or instance not pure HTML).
- **Why is not working here**: You have only one Vue instance for
  `<radio-input/>` that is sort of parent so defining `prop` onto it is
  meaningless since there is no parent Vue that can pass this. [Read
  Some More](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)
- In this case you could simply remove the `prop` and the binding value
  altogether and use `personal` text directly from data property
  `value` that u've defined, if that's what you want.

```
    <html>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>
          <radio-input></radio-input>
          <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
          <script>
             radioInput = new Vue({
               template: '<label>\n' +
                 ' <input type="radio" :name="name" :value="value" :v-model="v_model" :required="required">\n' +
                 ' <span>${ value }</span>\n' +
                 '</label>\n',
               delimiters: ['${', '}'],
               el: 'radio-input',
               data: {
                 name: 'A1_P1_S1_B0',
                 value: 'personal',
                 v_model: 'A1P1S1Q',
                 required: true,
               }
             });
          </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I tried this solution. However "personal" text is not printed.

Comment: @HyeonDo Can you give reproducible code for this in form of code snippet or codepen or any other.

Comment: [This link](https://codepen.io/ji5485/pen/OJLgLao) is Vue application that embody that codes.

Comment: @HyeonDo Added some explanation around the problem and snippet you provided in the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I solved this problem by creating a parent component and delivering props based on your advice.